# Why do parton distribution functions not depend on the total momentum of the composite state?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, partons

When defining such quantity as the elastic form factor, I kinda understand why it turns out to be independent of the momentum of the charged particle, and only dependent on the momentum of the photon used for probing it:
$$
\langle P | J^\mu| P'\rangle = (P-P')^\mu F(Q^2)
$$
In 6th chapter of Peskin one can find the explanation why in this case $F$ depends solely on $Q^2$.

Is there some argument why parton distribution functions only depend on the carried momentum fraction $x$ and the momentum cut-off? The latter is clearly not the same as the momentum of the initial state, even though oftentimes said to "set the scale" of the problem.

Let's fix the momentum scale $\Lambda$, and perform two calculations: for the total momenta $P_1$ and $P_2$ of the composite state, let's calculate the PDF of a certain constituent. Why is it obvious that $f(x,\Lambda)$ will be same in both cases?

Why in this scenario do we use the momentum cut-off? And do not bother about it in the case of form-factors...